# Can we use PDF4Net with PDF Form that contains a sub-table of data?

Tags: pdf-generation

We currently use PDF4NET on our servers for dynamic pdf generation.

We need to dynamic PDF which contains a number of single use fields, plus table of parts nested in the larger form that contain the same number of fields (part number, CSID, Revision, and such) a dynamic number of times (1-1000 rows).

Can we do this using a PDF Form created in Designer and populated with PDF4NET, or do we need to look at another course of action?

Edit to add:  I'm not the developer who would be implementing this functionality, and I don't have the means to this directly. I don't use the component myself, so I'm not familiar with it's capabilities nor do I have the opportunity to just try it out and see what happens.  As for contacting their support desk - I generally find SO to be a faster source of information.

Comment: So, like, what happened when you tried it?  PDF4NET is propriety software, isn't it?  Did you contact their support desk?  Just askin' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF4NET cannot fill dynamic Adobe Designer forms.
Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops PDF4NET.

Comment: @iPDFdev - you really shouldn't encourage turkeys like this to "bypass channels".  Maybe your company is small enough that *you* are both "development" *and* "support".  But otherwise, if you have a formal support desk - then you've just *undercut* them.  Not cool.  IMHO... :(

Comment: We have a dedicated support team but our support policy is to answer any questions asked on various forums in the same place where they were asked. Although we do not encourage this, we cannot ignore these questions. It is more complicated for us but if it is easier for the developer asking the question, what can we do? :)